# Subscribe and Unsubscribe Observable in ionic typescript

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, observable, subscribe

Using radio list where values are 5, 15, 20 and 30 mins. By default 15 mins are selected.

Now I need to constantly check function, when 5 seconds is selected. 
when 15 seconds radio button is selected then unsubscribe observable of 5 second and start 15 second subsciber using Observable.

When app is in background I need to constantly check the above scenario which radio list value is selected and basis on value I need to start Observable.

I am using ionic framework (code below), When to subscribe and unsubscribe?

```
 this.timerOneHourSubscription = Observable.interval(15000)
            .subscribe((val) => { 
      }
```

Example below:

```
 timerOneHourSubscription: Subscription;
 constructor() {
    this.showBadge();
   }
  }
 /**
 * This function allows to display badge on app icon
 */
showBadge() {
 //by default one hour subscription
 var refreshInterval = 
localStore.getPersistedData(localApp.ISRADIOGROUP_KEY);
 console.log('refreshInterval', refreshInterval);
 this.timerOneHourSubscription = Observable.interval(refreshInterval)
    .subscribe((val) => {
    if (localStore.getPersistedData(localApp.ISRADIOGROUP_KEY) != null) {
        if (localStore.getPersistedData(local.ISBADGE_ENABLED_KEY) != null) {
            let badgeToggleEnable = local.getPersistedData(local.ISBADGE_ENABLED_KEY);
            if (badgeToggleEnable) {
                if (this.Items != null) {
                    if (localStore.getPersistedData(localApp.ITEMS_KEY) != null) {
                        this.Items = localStore.getPersistedData(localApp.ITEMS_KEY);
                        var count = 0;
                        for (let i = 0; i < this.Items.length; i++) {
                        var unRead= this.Items[i].unRead;
                        if (unRead) {
                           count++;
                        }
                        }
                        this.badge.set(unRead++);
                    }
                }
                }
                else {
                    this.badge.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to clear your subscription and call a new subscription.

```
Observable.interval(15000).takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
      .subscribe(() => {
```

This will help you when you want to destroy the current subscription and start a new one.

To destroy the current one you can use below:-

```
this.onDestroy$.next();
```

You would have to declare the below at the top of you page:-

```
private onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();
```

Instead of sending a static value in the Observable try sending a method and call the same method again and again.

Comment: Abhishek, Thank you.. I am using typescript and ionic code

Comment: @AndroidGeeks: this code would work in ionic and Typescript because I have used it for myself as well.

Comment: @AndroidGeeks If you find this solution helpful, mark it to correct as this might help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution before selecting any radiobutton unsubscribe observable and start it again

```
unSubscribetimerhourSubscription() {
  this.timerhourSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```